# jQuery unintentional delay when hiding/showing content

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you go to a specific URL there the initial content gets loaded and then it interprets the url params, then the content changes.

On my local machine this happens "lickety split", aka so fast you can't see any delay. However, if you go to that URL after about 5 seconds the content finally hides and shows the correct content. The js is below and here is a little html snippet that is pretty close.

example URL: www.example.com/page1.aspx?nav=2012?id=113&pid=2

**HTML**:

```
  <div id="default">content</div>   
  <div id="mobile2012" style="display:none;">content</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
var querystring = location.search.replace('?', '').split('?');
var queryObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < querystring.length; i++) {
    var name = querystring[i].split('=')[0];
    var value = querystring[i].split('=')[1];

    queryObj[name] = value;
}
////////
var subNavDestination = queryObj["nav"];
////////
urlParams(subNavDestination);
function urlParams(subNavDestination) {
    var displayInformation;

    switch (subNavDestination) {
        case 'about': displayInformation = "AboutEarthquakeIns";
            break;
        case 'homeowner': displayInformation = "Homeowner2012Content";
            break;
        case 'renter': displayInformation = "Renter2012Content";
            break;
        case 'mobilehome': displayInformation = "Mobilehome2012Content";
            break;
        case 'condo': displayInformation = "Condominium2012Content";
            break;
        case '2011': displayInformation = "pdf2011";
            break;
        case '2012': displayInformation = "pdf2012";
            break;
        default: displayInformation = "GeneralContent";
    }

    if (displayInformation != "AboutEarthquakeIns") {
        //$('#PolicyTypes2012 .sideNavPolicyType').slideToggle();
        $('#PolicyTypes2011 .sideNavCoverage').slideUp();
    }

    if (displayInformation == "pdf2011") {
        controlContentVisibility("pdf2011");
        $('#PolicyTypes2011 .sideNavPolicyType').slideToggle();
        $('#PolicyTypes2011 .sideNavCoverage').slideUp();
        setActiveLink();
        setSelectedPolicyType();
        hideYearSubMenus(2012);
    }
    else if (displayInformation == "pdf2012") {
        controlContentVisibility("pdf2012");
        $('#PolicyTypes2012 .sideNavPolicyType').slideToggle();
        $('#PolicyTypes2012 .sideNavCoverage').slideUp();
        setActiveLink();
        setSelectedPolicyType();
        hideYearSubMenus(2011);
    }

    controlContentVisibility(displayInformation);
}
```

Comment: Rethink your structure.  Why serve all of this data to the client and then hide most of it?  Inefficient and certainly will lead to a undesirable user experience.

Comment: Also, your query string syntax is incorrect.  There should *never* be more than one question mark.

Comment: There is a content management system that is messing with the query string params that I don't have control of, that's why it has two ?'s. As to serving all this content to the user.... it's 90% text and I'm trying to avoid having multiple pages of crap. Thanks for your thoughts though.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the URL (I am assuming at a remote site), there is extra time needed to load the content of the div that you will choose show before they can be parsed/rendered.

Comment: This is actually rendered with the page though, so I'm not thinking this would be it.

Comment: I disabled all content from showing first and only show the requested and it's still slow.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have included javascript as part of separate script i.e .js file not the html file and delay you are seeing is time taken by browser to download that script

Comment: Even when it's inline, I still have the same issues.

Comment: It seems like it knows what to do and just waits until everything finishes loading EVERYTHING in the aspx page before switching out the content. The hard part with this is that the default content is loaded as one of the first things. I got the time down to half by removing an extra include file.